Hibernate can't find a table from postgresql database
Well, I have a postgresql database and table:
Structure in postgresql
So, i want to get all records from "SheduleRecords" table using Hibernate.
Table structure:
All types are "character varying"
So, go to my java classes:
I have a model for this table:
Model
But when i try to get the records from my java code, it fails:
Request code
Hibernate logs and message mistake
So, can somebody help me? I'm really stucked :(
By the way, configuration code:
Config hibernate
I tried to change configuration file or write table name with schema (public.SheduleRecords), but it did not help.

Classical problem with UPPER case. Don't use UPPER case, only lower case. Or be prepared to use double quotes " always and forever. Change SheduleRecords to shedulerecords or something like that.
